# Make DataBase portable

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I'm developing a local application with a DataBase in SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio, C#, I created and connected to the Database in the application, but when I pass to work to another computer, copy the all solution files, the information that had been saved in it doesn't exist, actually the entire Database doesn't exist, so I ask: have a way to package the data and make it accessible in other computers (not at the same time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you wish to achieve?

- If you want a common database location which should be accessed by all, then you'd need to make certain that other machines have access to your local machine's database server
- If you want the entire code plus the database to be present separately on each machine, then you'd need to share a database backup along with the application code folder and each machine would require the database backup to be restored on their database server along with setting up the application.

Answer (score 3):

For a desktop application, you might want to try something like Sql Server Compact Edition or Sqlite.  That should allow you to easily move the data file from computer to computer without needing to install a full database server.

Comment: SQLCE should do nicely if he's already running SQL Server 2008

Comment: I've already trySQL Server Compact Edition, but this didn't have all the tools necessary to accomplish what I wanted to do. In other way I have the same server and the data wasn't copy to the other computer. To do this I create Visual Studio 2010 with a SQL Database 2008 Project

Comment: You should get something really hot, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx